# Absolute value inequality with two unknows: x and y

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I have a problem that kept me all day and I can't see the solution. I'm in 10th Class, so if you can solve with easy steps, it will be very useful for me. So the exercise is: $|x+1|+|y-2x|≤4$    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I_HePaJiHDO1ziLW8cN6q_DCtFXz4zkW/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried with interval notation, to determine when x+1 is negative and positive. Then to substitute x with a number from the negative interval, so to find y. But I believe this is a very sily mistake.

Comment: Can you show your work?

Comment: @DennisGuglea You should post your cases ...

Comment: Based on the comments, I suppose that this is a very simple exercise

Comment: It's not a simple exercise, it does take time and diligence. We can't help you if we don't know where you're getting stuck or making a mistake. If you edit the question and include the work you've tried so far, we know how to help.

Comment: Ok, I understood.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would approach this by thinking about cases. Since the two terms on the left-hand side are both absolute values, we know they must each be greater than 0. We also know that they must each be less than 4. What happens if $|x+1| = 0$? What happens if $|x+1| = 4$? And what happens if $|x+1| = b$, where $0<b<4$?

Comment: I tried but I don't have ideas. I don't know how to continue. I understand the idea of Amaan M, but I don't how to develop it. I need to go to sleep, it's midnight here in Europe. I will try again tomorrow